# Is Visa required in Narita Aiport for changing terminals from T2 to T1

Tags: nrt

i will be traveling from India to Canada. i have to change flight at Narita airport. my onward flight is from different terminal. do i need visa for changing terminals at Narita from T2 to T1
Thanks

Comment: Are your flights on a single booking or separate tickets?

Comment: my flights are on single booking.

Answer (score 4):

You can [transfer between T2 and T1](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/connect/inter/inter_inter_t2/) using an airside shuttle bus. (This is different from the landside shuttle bus between terminals that most people seem to know about.)

You can get the bus at two points in T2: at gate 80 in the satellite building, or at gate 70 in the main building. These drop off at gate 28 and gate 59 in T1, respectively. In each case you will go through security before boarding the transit bus. Follow the signs for "International Connecting Flights" to the transit security checkpoint.

If you haven't got a boarding pass for your next flight segment, go to the transfer counter first, to pick it up. It is next to security.

Comment: Thank you Dear Michael for helping me. It means I don't require any transit visa for changing Terminals at Narita Airport.

Answer (score -2):

The information I got from the VFS was if your connecting flight is at the different terminal you need a transit visa. I would recommend you directly contacting the Japanese Embassy.